# How to run my node.js file when trigger button in html

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

First of all, today is my first time that i worked with node.js. So, excuse me if my questions are very simple for you.
I'm writing you because i can't find similar solutions to my problem.
I want to press an html button and then i want to trigger my test.js file.
Do you know if i can insert the following code inside my js file? Is there an another way that we run the node.js files inside html?

Here is my code: (by the way is right the window redirection??)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "testaki1"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var someVar = [];
  con.query("SELECT site_id FROM testaki12 WHERE user_id = '5'", function (err, rows) {
    if (err){ 
        throw err;
    }
    else {
        setValue(rows);
    }
  });

  function setValue(value) {
  someVar = value;
  console.log(someVar);
}

if (someVar == 1)
{
    res.send('<script>window.location.href="https://www.google.gr/?hl=el";</script>');
}
});
```

Comment: You can't run node.js files inside HTML, no - nodejs runs on the server (like PHP and other languages you can use for server-side development), not the client. You're probably looking to use Ajax here in order to make a request to your nodejs endpoint.

Comment: You can use a framework on top of NodeJS like ExpressJS, then create a route. Your front-end (html/js), like @RobinZigmond said, will do an GET Request to the back-end (node/express) and return the data with the response object like in your code.

Comment: thank you guys for your contribution..im gonna look at it..